# While validating the app occur An ssl error

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

[image]

While validating the app after archive in ios getting this error.

Also Occurs this error after restarting the machine and xcode.

Comment: Apple's servers are probably swamped right now with Yosemite downloads. Try again later.

Comment: an ssl error has occured. i did't get until today, what should i do